# Passing variables to an Action Event

Tags: java, user-interface, variables, parameter-passing

I am looking to pass variables from 3 ActionPerformed methods, or find an alternate way besides passing, to my jButtonActionPerformed method.  Trying to figure out this scope issue.

Here is a sample of one actionperformed method, for example I want to pass payment over:

```
private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    monthlyPayment = jTextField4.getText();
    payment = Float.parseFloat(monthlyPayment);
}
```

This is the method where I need payment passed to:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int months = 0;
    while (owed > 0){

        //for loop simulates a year
        for(int i=0; i<=11; i++){
            //break from loop if paid off!
            if (owed == 0){
                break;
            }
            owed -= payment;
            //counter for months
            months ++;
             }

        //adding interest
        owed*=rate;
    }

    String monthTotal = Integer.toString(months);
    jTextField5.setText(monthTotal);
}
```

Comment: you use 3 class level variable and use them in your jButtonActionPerformed.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give an example?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait you mean increase the scope?  But in my example the values aren't being passed, even though the variables are in scope, so its the value that needs to be in scope.